# Mapkit Open Maps via Button

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have created a map-based app that has various annotations on a map that when clicked on open up a small info page as shown below.

[image: Display Page]

I am wondering how I can link the 'Open in Maps' button to take the coordinates of the annotation and open maps to provide a route from the users current location (already coded in) to the Annotation.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to create mapItem from location information and then use open in maps (https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapitem/1452239-openinmapswithlaunchoptions?language=objc)

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.7749,-122.4194);

MKPlacemark *placeMark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placeMark];

NSMutableDictionary *launchOptions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[launchOptions setObject:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving forKey:MKLaunchOptionsMapTypeKey];
[mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
```

Comment: `- (BOOL)openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)launchOptions;` Do i insert my annotation name in he `NSDictionary` section?

Comment: no thats launchoptuions that you can specify if you want specific behavior in Maps app. like standard map  / hybrid map or show traffic. You can also pass in nil to get default behavior. Here is link to documentation https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapitem/1658079-launch_options_dictionary_keys?language=objc

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example? Sorry, I don't really see how to create the mapItem.

Comment: Code snippet added.

Comment: Can you explain how this works? I tried using it in my own code with my own coord but got missing semi-colon errors. If the annotations already exist would a mapItem still need to be created for each annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Use `openInMapsWithLaunchOptions()`, as @TKearsley says.

To use that function, you need an `MKMapItem`.

If you look up `MKMapItem` in the docs, you can create an `MKMapItem` with the init method `init(placemark:)`, which expects an `MKPlacemark`.

So the next question is how do you create an `MKPlacemark`:

If you again consult the docs you'll find an initializer for `MKPlacemark`:

```
 init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)
```

So, bringing it all together:

Get the coordinate of your annotation.

Use the coordinate in a call to `MKPlacemark's` initializer:

```
 init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)
```

Then use the resulting `MKPlacemark` In MKMapItem's initializer: `init(placemark:)`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found this [tutorial online] (http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_Swift_iOS_8_MKMapItem_Application#Creating_the_MapItem_Project) and I was going to use a variation of the `showMap` however, while he is needing the postal address I am just mapping to the coordinates. do I need to use an address dictionary?

Comment: No, you can create an MKPlacemark with just coordinates. I name the initializer you'd use in my answer. It's also in the Xcode help for MKPlacemark.

Comment: Ok so I have done the following: `let elephantcoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.069741, 174.078113)` `elephant_place = init(placemark:elephantcoord)` and `elephantitem = init(placemark:elephantplace)` is this right?

Comment: Looks reasonable. The proof is whether it works. Try it and see.

Comment: You'll want to get the coordinates from your MKAnnotation rather than using constants, but that looks like reasonable test code.